# How to change the nth template parameter in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

If I am using the following type:

```
template<uint64_t f1 = 0, uint64_t f2 = 0, uint64_t f3 = 0, ..., uint64_t f10 = 0>
class Options;

using myOpts = Options<51, 8, 12>;
```

Would there be anyway I could do something equivalent to this pseudo code:

```
using newOpts = myOpts[6]<82>;
```

Which would keep all the existing template arguments and set the 7th one to `82`.

Comment: what is wrong with `using newOpts =Options<51,8,12,0,0,0,82>` ?

Comment: @user463035818 Because I am setting it in a `constexpr` function using an argument, so I don't actually know what is the `n`.

Comment: btw i think it is an interesting question, just wanted to know what is the usecase, maybe you can add a word or two to the question, because it isnt that obvious why the obvious solution is not fine

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux It is known at compile time, which is why I am using a `constexpr` function.

Comment: You cannot use a function parameter as a template argument, even if that function is constexpr.

Comment: @n.m. Oh, well in that case I'd just move the argument to a function template parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose a template `using` as follows

```
template <std::size_t Idx, std::uint64_t NewVal, typename MO>
using NewOpts = decltype(get_new_opt<Idx, NewVal>(std::declval<MO>()));
```

where `get_new_opts()` and `get_new_opts_helper()` are declared only helper functions as follows

```
template <std::size_t Idx, std::uint64_t NewVal, std::uint64_t ... Fs,
          std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr auto get_new_opt_helper (Options<Fs...>,
                                   std::index_sequence<Is...>)
   -> std::remove_reference_t<
         decltype( std::declval<Options<(Idx == Is ? NewVal : Fs)...>>() )>;


template <std::size_t Idx, std::uint64_t NewVal, std::uint64_t ... Fs>
constexpr auto get_new_opt (Options<Fs...> o)
   -> decltype( get_new_opt_helper<Idx, NewVal>
                  (o, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Fs)>{}) );
```

You can use `NewOpts` as follows

```
using new_opt    = NewOpts<6u, 82u, myOpts>;
```

The following is a full compiling (C++14, because uses `std::index_sequence`) example

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <utility>

template <std::uint64_t f1 = 0u, std::uint64_t f2 = 0u, std::uint64_t f3 = 0u,
          std::uint64_t f4 = 0u, std::uint64_t f5 = 0u, std::uint64_t f6 = 0u,
          std::uint64_t f7 = 0u, std::uint64_t f8 = 0u, std::uint64_t f9 = 0u,
          std::uint64_t f10 = 0u>
class Options
 { };

template <std::size_t Idx, std::uint64_t NewVal, std::uint64_t ... Fs,
          std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr auto get_new_opt_helper (Options<Fs...>,
                                   std::index_sequence<Is...>)
   -> std::remove_reference_t<
         decltype( std::declval<Options<(Idx == Is ? NewVal : Fs)...>>() )>;


template <std::size_t Idx, std::uint64_t NewVal, std::uint64_t ... Fs>
constexpr auto get_new_opt (Options<Fs...> o)
   -> decltype( get_new_opt_helper<Idx, NewVal>
                  (o, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Fs)>{}) );


template <std::size_t Idx, std::uint64_t NewVal, typename MO>
using NewOpts = decltype(get_new_opt<Idx, NewVal>(std::declval<MO>()));

int main ()
 {
   using myOpts     = Options<51u, 8u, 12u>;
   using new_opt    = NewOpts<6u, 82u, myOpts>;
   using target_opt = Options<51u, 8u, 12u, 0u, 0u, 0u, 82u>;

   static_assert( std::is_same<new_opt, target_opt>::value, "!" );
 }
```